# How can I find stuck at in f=ab+cd and f=(a+b)(c+d)?

Tags: boolean-algebra

I am finding a method which input is broken bit( assume that c is 1 stuck) at  \$f=ab+cd\$ and \$f=(a+b)(c+d)\$. I could use one way as follows.

```
abcd  f
0000 =0
0001 =1
...
```

I think This formal way is old so I want to know more better way.
How can I find which input is broken?

Update:
What if d is stuck as 1.

0
0->1 0

0
1->1 0

1
0->1 0/1

1
1->1 1

So we can know which port is stuck.

UPDATE :

I have updated the illustrate.

## Would you please let me know If the B is SA1, how can I use vector to detect B's SA1?

## A=1, B=0, C=0, D=0 , Is this right?

[image]

Comment: for f=(a+b)(c+d) you would have no way of knowing which of c or d (or both) were stuck at 1, by just measuring the output.

Comment: @HKOB yes its true !!

Comment: @HKOB no we can know that!

Comment: @JigarGandhi No we can know that!

Comment: @Carter Assume that `d` is having `SA1` and then how can you make sure that `c` is not having `SA1` , which input pattern can justify that `c` is having no `SA1` but its `d`.

Comment: @JigarGandhi Did you mean that we know that circuit have some fault but we don't know where?

Comment: @Carter Exactly.. if you say that circuit has fault you need to know where it is.. in order to solve it.
 on a lighter note : You don't need to clean the world , if your glass is dirty!

Comment: @JigarGandhi Thanks, but why can't it find the fault at  f=(a+b)(c+d) if the stuck 0,1 on c?

Comment: @Carter If you assume that `d` is not on `SA1` , pattern `a=1;b=x;c=0;d=0` will give you actual result if `c` is at `SA1` or not

Comment: @JigarGandhi What do you mean actual data? 0 or 1? If yes, What circuit is I can find fault? Does the circuit without actual data can be fault circuit? Please let me know step by step.

Comment: @Carter add the schematic. I posted it at first. any discussion without schematic will keep on continuing like that only

Comment: @JigarGandhi I have updated.

Comment: Huh? What's a "stick" bit?

Comment: @OlinLathrop would you let me know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5RpGT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Ideally draw the schematic for each expression on which you want to analyse SA1 (Struck At 1) fault.
Go for specific set of stimulus which can propagate the error or fault.
For e.g. if any of `OR` Gate is SA1 then proper input to none-faulty end is Logic 0 cause Logic 0 can propagate the fault .

Kindly update the question with Schematic Diagram.

---

### After schematic updates

Assume `c` as `SA1` (Hence I have fixed it at `Logic1`
Since output of `AND` is only 1 for both inputs are as `1`
hence any pattern with `AB` as `01` `01` or `11` does same drill
Now Since `c` is `SA1` we need to stimulate `cd` with `00` only thus output of `OR2` would be `Logic0` but since `c` is `SA1`, the `OR2` output will be `Logic1` Hence `AND1` will be `Logic1`

thus for inputs `abcd` and `o_f` faulty output & `o_r` logical output

```
+---+---+---+---+-----+-----+
| a | b | c | d | o_f | o_r |
+---+---+---+---+-----+-----+
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1   | 0   |
+---+---+---+---+-----+-----+
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1   | 0   |
+---+---+---+---+-----+-----+
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1   | 0   |
+---+---+---+---+-----+-----+
```

Comment: Thanks, did you mean the formal verification way? If so, It should be have very long expensive for probe test.

Comment: @Carter it might be formal verification. but Upload a Schematic so that I can illustrate for explanation.

Comment: JigarGandhi we can know that

Comment: Ok we need schematic diagram. I'll update.

Comment: Thanks Sir, would you please let me know about f=(AB)+(CD)?

Comment: Sir, Would you please let me know If the B SA1, how can I have detect vector?

Comment: B SA1 for which function?